# Singly Linked list selection sort

Tags: sorting, data-structures, singly-linked-list

Hey so I have a class SinglyLinkedList and it contains my Node class, iterator class, and implements the List ADT (I dont think i need to post my code but if I do let me know). My question is this:

If I want to make a selected sort method (bubble etc), would it be "best practice" to put the Selected Sort method in its own class, or should it be put within the singly linked list. I want to put it within the Singly Linked List so it can have access to directly manipulating the Nodes (as the node class within my singly linked list is private) as it would be more efficient. But for some reason, some part of me thinks it would be a good idea to have it within its own class...

Any ideas on what would be best practice? Should I have my selected sort method(for singly linked lists) within the SinglyLinkedList or in its own class?
(i am using java, but that doesn't matter to much I dont think).

Comment: [`StackExchange::CodeReview`](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask this question

Comment: Assuming that the sort will only be used for lists created from SinglyLinkedList class, then it would make sense to keep sort as part of that class. For example in C++, the template function std::list::sort() is the equivalent of a member of the std::list "class".

Comment: Great thats what I thought. Makes sense. And I will keep that in mind next time I post I havent explored this site p[roperly yet,